# c: catch a segfault in exec() which was run in a child process

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, popen

EDIT:

I am trying to write a simple smoketest, where all options and reasonable parameters are tested.

I used popen() to execute the program that should be tested.
Using this approach does not work, because if the process dies with a signal (SIGINT, SIGSEGV...) the pipe from popen() does not tell me what happend.

Writing a signal handler did not help since popen creates a new process that receives the signals but not my smoketest.

Thanks to the answers i used pipe(), fork() and execv() to create my own popen()-version.

When the program now segfaults there is the problem that the pipe is useless (a read caused weird behavior -> blocked the process until i send a sigkill to the parent!)

To avoid this i tried different things and my solution is the following (it is simple but it took me a while to figure it out). so here is my example-code:

```
static int child_dead = 0;

void sigaction_sigchld(int signal) { /* Child died */
    child_dead = 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *env[])
{
    char *crashing_program = "/program_path/and_name";
    int ret;
    int byte;

    pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0) /* Child */
    {
        execve(crashing_program, argv, env);

        /* if execve returns that it mus have failed! */
        fprintf(stderr, "Exec failed\n");
        _exit(-1);
    } else /* Parent */
    {
        if(!child_dead)
        {
            byte = read(pipe_out[1], line, BUFFSIZE);
            if(!byte){
                perror("Smoketest:Line:xxx");
            } else
            {
                fprintf(stdout, line);
            }
        }
        wait(&child_status);
        /*
          check if the child died with SIGSEGV etc
        */
    }
```

This seems to work fine as long as i only have one child at a time which is sufficient for me though. I anyone has a better idea or any tipps for me i would be glad to update this entry.

Last but not least: Of course using this method it is probably impossible to do any cleanup.

Cheers.

Answer (score 7):

See the documentation for [`waitpid(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid).  There are a bunch of macros you can use to test how the child process was terminated.  In particular, you can use `WIFSIGNALED()` and `WTERMSIG()` to test if the child process was terminated by a signal, and if so, which signal:

```
int status = pclose(...);
if (WIFSIGNALED(status))
{
    // It was terminated by a signal
    if (WTERMSIG(status) == SIGSEGV)
    {
        // It was terminated by a segfault
    }
}
```

Edit: As stated in the comments, you'd rather make use of fork and exec, then use `waitpid(2)` to correctly update status.

Comment: `pclose()` is the correct place to obtain the exit status, but note that `WIFSIGNALED()` won't be true unless the shell invoked by `popen` itself crashed, rather than the command passed to `popen`.

Comment: caf is right here. You may need to use `fork` and `exec` and `pipe` to set up your own version of `popen` just so you can get more details.