# SIGSEGV signal handling in a child process

Tags: c

I have a program that creates a fork that uses execve to run a program that have a SegFault and exit after catching the signal. In my signal handler, I should obtain "Segmentation fault (Core dumped)" but nothing is written. So I'm asking : how to handle a segfault signal in a child process ? My code is the following :

```
int     child_management(char **env, char **arguments)
{
  char  **paths;
  char  *current_path;
  char  *target_path;
  int   found;
  int   i;

  i = -1;
  found = 0;
  paths = get_paths(env);
  if (execve(arguments[0], arguments, env) == -1)
    {
      while (paths[++i] != NULL)
        {
          current_path = my_strcat(paths[i], "/");
          target_path = my_strcat(current_path, arguments[0]);
          found = (execve(target_path, arguments, env) == -1 && found == 0) ? 0 : 1;
          free(current_path);
          free(target_path);
        }
      if (!found && !is_existing_builtin(arguments[0]))
        my_printf("%s: Command not found.\n", arguments[0]);
    }
  free(arguments);
  free(paths);
  if (signal(SIGSEGV, segf_handler) == SIG_ERR);
  exit(0);
}

void    segf_handler()
{
  my_printf("Segmentation fault (Core dumped)\n");
}

int     execute_program(char *str, char **av, char **env)
{
  pid_t pid;
  char  **arguments;

  pid = fork();
  arguments = my_str_explode(str, ' ');
  if (pid > 0)
    {
      parent_management(pid, arguments, env);
    }
  else if (pid == 0)
    {
      child_management(env, arguments);
    }
}
```

Please notice that I am doing an exercice and I'm not allowed to use another function than signal so don't tell me about sigaction

Comment: Perhaps your `my_printf` is broken? Or the segfault is not happening? BTW, if `execve` is successful you will never get to the `signal` function at all...

Comment: Even with a normal printf, it doesn't work. And if I launch the specified program with bash, it segfaults !

Comment: As I said in the update: `execve` is not returning if successful.

Comment: Thanks but if you relook at the code you'll see that signal is out of the condition statement.

Comment: So? It won't ever get there.

Comment: Why not ? The program doesn't exit if there's a segfault

Comment: You call `execve` **before** you call `signal`. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes but if I don't how am I supposed to handle the error ?

Comment: Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339664/c-catch-a-segfault-in-exec-which-was-run-in-a-child-process BTW, I think it's a duplicate...

Comment: Nop, like I said, I have to use signal function. I can't use any other function...

Comment: Good luck then. You will need it.

Comment: What is this `if`-statement for: `if (signal(SIGSEGV, segf_handler) == SIG_ERR);`

Comment: It's a a precaution because when my problem will be solved, I suppose that I'll need it.

Comment: The moment an `exec*()` was successful any signal handler established by the process calling the `exec*()` function is gone, as the successful call to `exec*()` replaced the whole process with the process `exec*()`ed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't catch the SEGV signal inside the child because calling execve replaces the code running in the child with that program.

You can however catch the CHLD signal in the parent when the child process dies. You'll need to examine the status returned from wait() to see how/why it died though.

Comment: This solved my problem because it caused me to ask someone to know if I could use the macros and I could ! Thanks !